# Whether selenium Standalone server 2.53 support fire fox browser 49.0 version? If not means what is the solutions

Tags: selenium-webdriver

**Whether selenium Standalone server 2.53 support  fire fox browser 49.0 version? *If not means what is the solutions***

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 2.53.0 supports FF 49.0. 
You can download geckodriver from the link
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
Then save the file in your local system. unzip the file and change the application name as "wires.exe". 
Then specify the path upto wires.exe in the code.

add selenium-2.53.0 jar files.

Try below code to start working on FF 47.0 or above.

```
package com.marionette.programs;
```

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.MarionetteDriver;

public class HandleLatestFirefox {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.out.println(currentDir);
    //String marionetteDriverLocation = currentDir + "G:\\ravik\\Ravi-Training\\Selenium\\Marionette for firefox\\wires.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "G:\\ravik\\Ravi-Training\\Selenium\\Marionette for firefox\\wires.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdgc21jJHOAhVCvY8KHZ4aCdcQPAgD");
    System.out.println("marionette working fine....");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I referred to this example. This may help you.
http://howtoselenium.blogspot.ca/2016/08/this-is-how-to-use-selenium-geckodriver.html